# Override Function by extending it and based on a condition execute the extended function

Tags: javascript

I have a function, i want to override this function and then i want to execute the overridden function based on few global values.

```
var myName = 'Raju';
function x() {
  console.log(myName);
}

//Now extend the function and based on condition like if myName === 'Raju' alert the name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you!

```js
var myName = 'Raju';
function x() {
  console.log(myName);
}

// overwrite the global function, passing the old function as oldFn
x = (function(oldFn) {
  function extendedFn() {
    oldFn();
    if (myName == 'Raju') {
      alert('hi');
    }
  }
  return extendedFn;
})(x);


x();
```

Comment: Sure. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can override function like this:

```js
var myName = 'Raju';

function x() {
  console.log(myName);
}

var orgX = x;

x = function() {
  console.log('Hello');
  if(myName == 'Raju') {
     orgX();
  }
}  

x();
```

Comment: User was asking the function to be extended, else this is also a valid answer. Good one!

Comment: Yes! @NikhileshShivarathri you're correct. I need extended function. Thank you!